# Replace all NA entries in R table with different random

Tags: r, csv

I have a large table in R with a bunch of columns that are all NA.  I want to replace each NA cell with a randomly sampled number from another table, like so:

```
dataTable=read.csv("my-data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",
                   dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")

randValues <-c(0,0.3,-0.3)

dataTable[is.na(dataTable)] <- sample(randValues,1)
```

The problem is that each cell gets replaced with the SAME randomly selected number from randTable.  How do I get a different number for each cell?

Comment: Does `dataTable[is.na(dataTable)] <- sample(randValues,sum(is.na(dataTable)))` works?

Comment: @Emer I had the same thought, but added `replace=TRUE` so you don't run out of values to sample.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing (something similar to) imputation of missing data, so you may want to look at packages which are written for that purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `sample(randValues, sum(is.na(dataTable)),replace=TRUE)` This guarantees you'll get as many independent samples as there are `NA` values, as well as allowing for the same value to be randomly selected each time.  (The `sum` function coerces the `logical` output to numeric ones and zeroes)

Comment: accepted answer works great, thanks. Is there an easy way to bias the sample, say if I want 75% of the random values to be -0.3 ?

Comment: Yes, you can either add a set of weights via the `prob` argument or just write `randValues<-c(rep(-.3,75),rep(0,12),rep(+.3,13))`